# Dynamic Queue Worker Laravel With Supervisor and redis Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

here is my code when I dispatch the queue jobs dynamically

```
class Api
{

    public static function send_message($recipientNumber,$messageData,$user,$flag= 0)
        {
            
                $user_id = $user->id;
                $queue_name = 'laravel-worker-dynamic-'.$user_id;
            return SendMessageJob::dispatch($recipientNumber, $messageData, $user, $flag)->onQueue($queue_name);

        }
   
}
```

here is my supervisor's code using Wildcard

```
[program:laravel-worker-dynamic-*]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /var/www/html/WaBussiness/artisan queue:work redis --queue=%(program_name)s:* --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data ; ubuntu
numprocs=1 ; Set the number of worker processes
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/WaBussiness/storage/logs/worker.log
```

When I dispatch queue jobs dynamically, all of them remain in a pending state, but Supervisor does not process them. However, when I configure it statically, it works. I want Supervisor to dynamically handle the queue jobs

when dynamically queue job dispatch superviosr process them.